updates to ubuntu 24.04
When Ubuntu 24.04 comes out in about 2 days, there is probably going to be some important things that need fixing.  Will the initial .iso file for the release be updated as needed to reflect such changes or, will it rely solely on "apt-get upgrade" for these initial corrections.
Said another way, is it worth waiting a couple weeks before downloading the new release .iso file?

You don't update the initial .iso-file, just update your system. It does not depend solely on apt upgrade, other methods such as unattended upgrades are sufficient as well. The second part of your question is opinion based and the answer depends on your personal preferences, do you want newer software versions or do you need proven stability...

Usually, the first LTS ISO update is made in August - in this case, August 2024.

Thanks for approximately dating the first update.  If 24.01 was late May I might wait but August is half way to whatever the "O" named critter is (24.10).

Look at the status page for 24.04 if you want details of what bugs are being fixed before release (ie. those impacting the install itself) OR those that are listed as SRU bugs (ie. fixed post-install via upgrades).  The detail isn't exactly hidden (though https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/noble-numbat-24-04-release-status-tracking/44043 contains only a partial list, with more available on launchpad itself).   Bugs specific to to installer (which is a snap package) will be updated post-install, as the installer can update itself if internet is available during post-release install.

FYI:   SRU = Stable Release Update... the process that allows packages to updated post-release; the list of "Release day SRUs" are somewhat key fixes that should exist on systems BUT are not critical to the install itself (thus can be updated post-install)

simple answer to your question is - yes. Worthwhile waiting at least until the final release although conventional wisdom suggests waiting until the first point release (24.04.1) particularly if you have mission critical requirements when many of the initial niggles will have been identified and ironed out.
